# Repeated independent variables with frequency dependant variable

Tags: variables, sum, frequency, spss

So I have a list of numbers for my independent variable (Species ID number) which are repeated; each Species ID number has a corresponding dependent value (count).

What I need is a list of the species with a sum of all their corresponding counts.

Is this possible in SPSS?

Answer (score 1):

Look up documentation for [AGGREGATE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/base/syn_aggregate.dita) and/or [CTABLES](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_23.0.0/spss/tables/syn_ctables.dita)*

*Requires add-on module licence

Your code would look something like this:

```
AGGREGATE OUTFILE=dsAgg /BREAK=SpeciesID /TallyDV=sum(DepenVar).
CTABLES /TABLE SpeciesID[c] BY DepenVar[S][SUM].
```